# Tornado : support multiple Application on same IOLoop

Tags: python, web-applications, tornado

I'm wondering if it is possible in the [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org) framework to register multiple [Application](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/web.html#application-configuration) on the same IOLoop ?

Something like

```
application1 = web.Application([
    (r"/", MainPageHandler),
])
http_server = httpserver.HTTPServer(application1)
http_server.listen(8080)

application2 = web.Application([
    (r"/appli2", MainPageHandler2),
])
http_server2 = httpserver.HTTPServer(application2)
http_server2.listen(8080)

ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Basically I'm trying to structure my webapp so that:

1. functional applications are separated
2. multiple handlers with the same purpose (e.g. admin/monitoring/etc) are possible on each webapp

Comment: Is there any specific reason you need two semantically-separate `Application`s?

Comment: well, it's more a functional need than a technical one. basically I wanted to host two applications on the same Tornado container (à la Tomcat); but it seems this isn't the right pattern here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simple thing is if you were to bind your applications to different ports:

```
...
http_server = httpserver.HTTPServer(application1)
http_server.listen(8080)    # NOTE - port 8080

...
http_server2 = httpserver.HTTPServer(application2)
http_server2.listen(8081)   # NOTE - port 8081

ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

This is the base case that Tornado makes easy.  The challenge is that by routing to applications at the URI level you're crossing a design boundary which is that each application is responsible for all of the URIs that that are requested by it.

If they all really need to be serviced at the URI level not port, it would probably be best to  host different applications on different ports and have Nginx/Apache do the URI routing - anything that involves messing with the Application/Request handling is going to be a world of hurt.